# How can I obtain user's last active time when using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Suppose Users are spending long time in the web-site.
How can I obtain user's last active time.
Last active time means the last timestamp of user who requested(accessed to the page. user even doesn't need to update or create new record) to app.

A User might have signed in about an hour ago. Then he's still web surfing in my web site.
I want the time of last request the user sent.

Is it possible?

Devise has **current_sign_in_at** but not last active time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The way I would implement this is to add a `last_active_at` datetime column to the User model, then putting something in my controller:

```rb
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :record_user_activity

  private

  def record_user_activity
    if current_user
      current_user.touch :last_active_at
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm using ajax's setInterval so every time it reloads automatically, it update this **last_active_at** how can I set it up exception? the action is 'community#refresh'

Comment: If you're using setInterval to periodically send an AJAX call back to the server and fetch new data, then you shouldn't need to do anything. The filter will still run before the community#refresh action, even if it's coming in through AJAX, as long as the user has cookies on and there isn't anything else that could disrupt the user's session.

Comment: Would it be better to use after_filter, or would it not really matter?

Comment: An `after_filter` will run after the action finishes, but before the HTTP response is sent back to the user's browser. There is some difference there. For example, if `touch :last_active_at` fails, do you want it to fail _before_ or _after_ you perform whatever action the user is attempting? No one right answer, but I'd lean toward the `before_filter`.

Comment: This would add an I/O appending of every single request. If you want a site that scales, I would avoid doing something like this.